# javascript events fired in wrong order in IE8 and IE7 (Telerik radgrid)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using a telerik radgrid and have wired up a number of methods as you can see below.

In firefox, chrome and IE9 the events fire in the following order:

```
RowClick
RowSelecting
RowSelected
```

In IE8 and IE7 the events are firing in the following order:

```
RowSelecting
RowSelected
RowClick
```

Is there a way to reorder the events in IE8 and IE7?

```
var originalClickedRowState = null;
var clickedRow = null;

function rgGrid_OnRowCreating(sender, args) {}
function rgGrid_OnRowCreated(sender, args) {}

function rgGrid_OnRowClick(sender, args) {
    clickedRow = args.get_gridDataItem();
    originalClickedRowState = args.get_gridDataItem().get_selected();
}

function rgGrid_OnRowDeselecting(sender, args) {
    if (clickedRow != null && clickedRow != args.get_gridDataItem()) {
       args.set_cancel(true);
    }
}

function rgGrid_OnRowSelecting(sender, args) {
    if (clickedRow == args.get_gridDataItem() && originalClickedRowState) {
        args.set_cancel(true);
    originalClickedRowState = null;
    clickedRow = null;
}
}

function rgGrid_OnRowSelected(sender, args) {
    originalClickedRowState = null;
    clickedRow = null;    
}
```

I wire up these methods in the radgrid

```
<ClientSettings >
    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"  />
    <ClientEvents
        OnRowCreated="rgGrid_OnRowCreated"
    OnRowCreating="rgGrid_OnRowCreating" 
    OnRowClick="rgGrid_OnRowClick" 
    OnRowDeselecting="rgGrid_OnRowDeselecting"
        OnRowDeselected="RowDeselected"
        OnRowSelecting="rgGrid_OnRowSelecting"
       OnRowSelected="rgGrid_OnRowSelected" />                                           
    <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" />
</ClientSettings>
```

**EDIT:**
I have edited the question to show the code I am using. My events are being called before radgrids events.
I need the events to fire in the correct order as I need to get which row was selected before determining if any other rows should be deselected.

I got the code from this forum post on [telerik](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/multi-select-with-using-ctrl.aspx) and I dont know enough about telerik to rewrite the code I have to work in IE8 and IE7.

Answer (score 2):

You should not rely on event order in your applications.

Have a look on this : http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: You answer is correct as far best practice but it doesn't resolve the question.